# Check if router.url contains specific string?

Tags: angular

I have this :

```
   if (this.router.url === '/test/sort') {

                    this.active = 0;
                }
```

Problem is that sometimes url will be `test/sort?procesId=11` and than it will not enter in if statement. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want something basic that works:

```
if (this.router.url.indexOf('/test/sort') > -1) {
  this.active = 0;
}
```

Comment: I am tempted to downvote this answer on the basis that you have said it isn't a good answer and there are far better solutions...

Answer (score 26):

You can also use:

```
if (this.router.url.includes('/test/sort')) 
{  
     this.active = 0; 
}
```

Method `String.includes(searchString: string, position?: number): boolean` - Returns `true` if `searchString` appears as a substring of the result of converting this object to a String, at one or more positions that are greater than or equal to position; otherwise, returns false.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LocationStrategy to get url without parameters.

```
import {LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private url:LocationStrategy) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        console.log(this.url.path());
        if(this.url.path()==='/test/sort'){

         this.active=0; 
         }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be another possibility:

```ts
if (this.activatedRouter.snapshot.url.some(url => url.path.includes('test')) &&
    this.activatedRouter.snapshot.url.some(url => url.path.includes('sort'))) {
    this.active = 0;
}
```

Modify it for your needs.